# Ubuntu: configure folder is not under the directory crosstool-ng

Tags: ubuntu, crosstool-ng

I'm new with ubuntu and I need to install crosstool-ng in my VM following these steps :

1 mkdir test

2 cd test

3 git clone https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng

4 ./bootstrap

5 ./configure --prefix=/home/khouloud/lab/test/crosstool-ng/ctng

but I got this error `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`
 in this step ` while running the 5th step

these are the files/folders listed under the directory **crosstool-ng**

```
khouloud@khouloud-VirtualBox:~/lab/test/crosstool-ng$ ls
bash-completion  COPYING            kconfig     Makefile.am  scripts
bootstrap        ct-ng.in           LICENSE     packages     testing
config           debian             licenses.d  paths.sh.in  TODO
configure.ac     docs               m4          README.md    verbatim-data.mk
contrib          issue_template.md  maintainer  samples
```

I don't know what went wrong while cloning crosstool-ng!

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `./bootstrap` before? [The documentation](https://crosstool-ng.github.io/docs/install/) states that this has to be done before executing `./configure`